# How can some multimeters automatically detect and measure the AC and DC voltage and current?

Tags: ac, dc, multimeter, amperage, voltmeter

I was wondering how there are multimeters that are able to measure voltage and current AC or DC automatically without setting the reading on AC or DC.

Comment: Direct connected multimeters and use of some "microcomputer" ...

Comment: And could also do RMS measurements as well as some others things ...

Comment: Which multimeters you mean? There is no multimeter that could determine what kind of measurements us humans want to make at any given time. It would be unsafe to switch between current or voltage or AC or DC, if the other one is expected.

Comment: @Justme I mean the multimeter that can determine AC / DC voltage and AC / DC current

Comment: How can it do that safely? If you measure a sine wave with range of 0 to 1V, how can the meter know.if you want to see the 0.5V AC amplitude or the 0.5V DC?

Comment: @Justme, one way is to display both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I was wondering how there are multimeters that are able to measure
> voltage and current AC or DC automatically without setting the reading
> on AC or DC*

I'd design a system that made simultaneous AC and DC measurements like this: -

[image]

With auto-ranging it would look something like this: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for the DC signal I know it's simple voltage dividers, and a current sensing resistor to get the DC voltage and current.

But for the AC part if want to measure it on the same channel I am measuring the DC voltage on without changing anything, how could this possibly be done?

Comment: @Shamooooot If the AC part of the signal is quite tiny compared to the DC part of the signal (for example), the MCU would apply auto-ranging on the high-pass output to get better AC signal resolution. If it were the other way round, auto-ranging would be applied on the low-pass signal output. In effect, the more sophisticated systems would have MCU controlled auto-ranging on both LP and HP outputs.

Comment: thank you again..
I was looking to use my data acquisition module which accepts 0-10V analog signal to detect both AC and DC voltage on the same channels due to the limited numbers of channels, however I am having a problem in converting the AC let's say 220v to DC as the only way I know is using the full wave bridge rectifier circuit, which will add the forward voltage drops of diodes to the resulted voltages.
Then if I have to go through this same circuit to measure the DC voltage, will the difference between the input and output be the same as the difference that would be found on the AC?

Comment: We design using more sophisticated circuits than simple bridge rectifiers (which also have other problems); we use either an RMS to DC converter as mentioned above or, a precision full wave rectifier built around an op-amp.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called auto ranging multimeters.These multimeters use a microprocessor to automatically select the appropriate measurement range and mode based on the input signal.

When you connect the probes to the circuit, the auto-ranging multimeter will measure the voltage or current and then select the range and mode that will give the most accurate measurement.

Comment: How would the microprocessor know what you want to measure about the thing where you have connected the leads?

Comment: Autoranging is typically for the magnitude (e.g., 2V vs. 20V vs. 200V), but not the *type* of measurement (AC vs. DC).